# Decoding a h.264 stream with MediaCodec

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, android-mediacodec, decoder

For my Quadcopter project I'm triying to display a raw H.264 stream on my android phone. The input stream comes from a TCP connection.
I did some researche in how decoders work and created the following decoder thread.
The SPS and PPS variables are retreived from the data in an other function, this should be working since I copied it from a working code.

```
private class PlayerThread extends Thread {
    private MediaCodec decoder;
    private Surface surface;

    public PlayerThread(Surface surface) {
        this.surface = surface;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        while(SPS == null || PPS == null || SPS.length == 0 || PPS.length == 0)
        {
            try 
            {
                Log.e("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: sps,pps not ready yet");
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: sps,pps READY");


            decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
            MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 640, 480);
            mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(SPS));
            mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(PPS));
            decoder.configure(mediaFormat, surface /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */);


        if (decoder == null) 
        {
            Log.e("DecodeActivity", "DECODER_THREAD:: Can't find video info!");
            return;
        }

        decoder.start();
        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: decoder.start() called");

        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();


        int i = 0;
        while(!Thread.interrupted())
        {
            Frame currentFrame = null;
            try 
            {
                Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: calling queue.take(), if there is no frame in the queue it will wait");
                currentFrame = queue.take();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                Log.e("EncodeDecode","DECODER_THREAD:: interrupted while PlayerThread was waiting for the next frame");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(currentFrame == null)
                Log.e("EncodeDecode","DECODER_THREAD:: null frame dequeued");
            else
                Log.d("EncodeDecode","DECODER_THREAD:: " + currentFrame.id + " no frame dequeued");

            if(currentFrame != null && currentFrame.frameData != null && currentFrame.frameData.length != 0)
            {
                Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: decoding frame no: " + i + " , dataLength = " + currentFrame.frameData.length);

                int inIndex = 0; 
                while ((inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1)) < 0)
                    ;

                if (inIndex >= 0) 
                {
                    Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: sample size: " + currentFrame.frameData.length);

                    ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                    buffer.clear();
                    buffer.put(currentFrame.frameData);
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, currentFrame.frameData.length, 33, 0);

                    BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
                    int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 100000);

                    switch (outIndex) 
                    {
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                        Log.e("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                        outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                        break;
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                        Log.e("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());

                        break;
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                        Log.e("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: decoded SUCCESSFULLY!!!");
                        ByteBuffer outbuffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
                        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        decoder.stop();
        decoder.release();

    }
}
```

This produces the next error: (i can't post pictures yet :(, so here is the link )
[Error_Log](http://puu.sh/dB3OJ/1365e66051.png)

I tested the data stream on a laptop with VLC and it shows the video, so I guess that part is working.
Also the application is creating a surface and it is showing that some data is received. But when it is trying to put the outputbuffer to the surface the application exits whit the error.

I'm new to decoding and this is my first android application, so I dont't realy know were to look. So I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

If you are intrested, my entire code is in this link:
[H264_video.java](https://github.com/Thijs84/test/blob/master/H264_video.java)

Comment: put VLC for android on the phone and use it as a client instead of MediaCodec handler for stream.

Comment: At least your algo (public static int find(byte[] source, byte[] match, int startIndex) that searches substring is not correct:
Consider how it works on source="AAABD", match="AABD", it will match nothing, while substring exist, such routine cannot be done in single pass. On mismatch you have to go back in source array, to next element, where you've started match character

Comment: The ISurfaceTexture::setBufferCount() failure seems suspicious.  Looks like you're just sending data to a SurfaceView though.  You may want to try feeding the data to MediaMuxer to create a .mp4 file, and then see if that plays back successfully.

Comment: Robert, a need a low delay stream so that unfortunately is not an option :(.
Ugene, the find routine seems to be working because i get the right SSP and PPS. But I will double check that.
Fadden, I thought a surface should play h264 format but I will test is MediaMuxer works.